# iMac late 2012 only connects to the higher 5GHz channels

Tags: network, wifi, imac, airport

I am facing a weirdo now. Out of the blue, my late 2012 iMac (Catalina) started to detect only the higher (above 48) 5GHz channels. These are DFS so not stable, hence as long as my router is permitted to keep one of the DFS channels for 5GHz I can get the iMac connected to the network. If the 5GHz channels switch below 50, the iMac only connects to 2.4GHz channels. The 5GHz is somehow detected by the iMac even if the channel is below 50, but gets never connected, asking for the key (even though it is stored in the system) and after providing it again, it does not get connected. This is weird since higher the channels are, more sensitive to the distance and perturbation are. I noticed no issues from the start, it popped up just recently, after being wired for months. I checked two different routers and the same issue persists. Only DFS 5GHz channels are used to get connected. Played with the level of the security keys - nothing worked. 2.4GHz works just fine, but it is low speed so not satisfactory enough.

Appreciate your suggestions.